# SqlAlchemy count after filtering rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following query to show users' requests. I want to count all requests and also those which has done (with done status). I can get the count of all but it returns nothing for count of done ones.

Also are there better ways to do this? I have a `requests` relationship in the Users model which might be useful.

```
sq_all = db.session.query(Requests.uid,
           func.count(Requests.id).label('requests_num'))\
           .group_by(Requests.uid).subquery()

sq_done = db.session.query(Requests.uid,
           func.count(Requests.id).label('done_num'))\
           .filter(Requests.status == RequestStatusEnum.done)\
           .group_by(Requests.uid).subquery()

query = db.session.query(Requests, Users, UserInfos, sq_all).\
        filter(Requests.uid == Users.id, 
               UserInfos.uid == Users.id, 
               Users.id == sq_all.c.uid)\
       .outerjoin(sq_done, Users.id == sq_done.c.uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to query the `sq_done` too, which was omitted:

```
query = db.session.query(Requests, Users, UserInfos, sq_all, sq_done).\
        filter(Requests.uid == Users.id, 
               UserInfos.uid == Users.id, 
               Users.id == sq_all.c.uid)\
       .outerjoin(sq_done, Users.id == sq_done.c.uid)
```